# JS Function not executed from Module

Tags: javascript, jquery

can anybody say me, why this kind of function will not be executed:

```
var textStyle = {
      color: function () {
             console.log('test')
             return 'red'
            }
      }
}
```

but this one works fine:

```
   var textStyle = {
          color: test()
          }
    }

 function test () {
    console.log('test');
        return 'red'
    }
```

Comment: The first sets the value of `textStyle.color` to a function, the second sets it to the result of running the function.

Comment: ahh..seems like there is no callback, to call the function afterwards. Thx!

Comment: You *can* do something like `color: (function () { ... })()` if you want to use anonymous functions

Comment: yep. thx again!

Answer (score 1):

I have added comments through your code to show you what is happening at each line and why you are getting the behaviour you see.

```
// define a variable textStyle as an object
var textStyle = {
      // with the property color, that refers to the following function
      color: function () {
             console.log('test')
             return 'red'
      }
}
```

Nowhere in this code do we invoke the function assigned to color.

Now the second snippet, I have changed the order to make it a little clearer (this is what actually happens in JavaScript - function definitions are hoisted)

```
//define a function called test
function test () {
    console.log('test');
    return 'red'
}

//define a variable textStyle as an object
var textStyle = {
      // with a property color, that refers to **the result** of calling the test function
      color: test()
}
```

Note that in this case we *are* invoking the function.

Answer (score 0):

You then have to do textStyle.color()

color is a function not its result.

color:test() will be what test returns, not the actual function.

You seem to also have an extra '}' as well.